# Estimate total stream length, frequency and order in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arc-hydro, stream

I am new to GIS, and I want to calculate the stream frequency and [Strahler stream order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strahler_number) in a watershed. I have already processed the DEM and there are 20 sub basins. A sample map what I want to get is attached.

Can someone give some guidance in this regard?

May be a link, steps or tutorial will be good.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

ArcGIS Desktop has an easy to use tool:

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/stream-order.htm

You'll need a stream and flow direction raster before you can run this tool.

The workflow is in the answers to
[Finding Stream Order from DEM using ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/40717/how-to-find-out-the-stream-order-from-dem)

That will tell you all you need to know.

Comment: I think thats not what i wanted to know, i already have stream order raster. i want to estimate the features shown in the figure attached.